# How to Test Independence of Poisson Variables?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, poisson-distribution, independence

I have a data set of length $10,000$. Each entry, $e_i$, of my data set is associated with two values, $x_i$ and $y_i$. Let $X$ and $Y$ represent the random variables for which my data set is a realization. I have found and tested from the data that the variables $X$ and $Y$, when considered separately, have Poisson distributions and I have used the data to estimate their parameters $\lambda_X$ and $\lambda_Y$. I believe that the two variables are nearly independent, which would give me the joint distribution of the variables--which is what I'm looking for.

How do I go about testing for independence when my hypothesis is that they are independent?

I was thinking about computing correlation but there are cases in which uncorrelated variables aren't independent.

Comment: A standard solution is the $\chi^2$ test.  Have you considered that and found it wanting for some reason?

Comment: I thought the x^2 test could only prove dependence? i.e. it assumed independence and then showed that your realization was very unlikely.

Comment: That's precisely what you are asking: when your hypothesis is that the variables are independent, then you look for evidence that they might not be. Lacking such evidence--and having a sufficiently large dataset (and 10,000 records seems like it might be enough for many applications)--it is justifiable to adopt the independence assumption. The situation is asymmetric: it is not possible statistically to test lack of independence without stipulating precisely and quantitatively *how* the variables would be dependent.

Comment: Interesting comment, especially the last part. So now I'm thinking I should just compute the chi square statistic and plot the variables against each other to test for any dependence. If i don't find any evidence for dependence, should i again compute a chi square goodness of fit for the joint Poisson distribution against the data?

Comment: I do not understand the distinction you are making between the two applications of the chi-squared test. In its usual incarnation you would use independent maximum likelihood estimates of $\lambda_X$ and $\lambda_Y$ and the independence assumption to predict the expectations of all $(X,Y)$ pairs, compute the $\chi^2$ statistic, and refer it to a $\chi^2$ distribution having two degrees of freedom less than the number of bins into which you put the data pairs. (You will likely have to create wide bins near the extremes of the data to assure the validity of the $\chi^2$ distribution.)

Comment: An alternative application simply computes the $\chi^2$ statistic for the two-way table of the data. This one assumes nothing about the marginal distributions of $X$ or $Y$ and merely evaluates independence. I suspect it would not be quite as relevant to you as the first (Poisson) application.

Comment: Ahh, I see what you mean. Thanks, what you're saying makes sense and should work.